# C++ - loading of dependent caches on process startup

Tags: c++, caching

I have a number of caches which are used inside applications and/or static libraries. For performance reasons, all the caches (implemented as singletons) used by an application and the respective libraries on which the application depends need to be preloaded on application startup. As a result, there is a long list of cache load function calls which is difficult to maintain - if a new cache is used in a library, it has to be added to the list of every application dependent on that library.

I considered a solution with self-registering classes but given the caches are in a static library, they wouldn't register. Keeping a list of classes to register defeats the purpose as it reintroduces the initial solution.

Next I am thinking of a solution involving some kind of a dependency map but I am eager to hear your solutions/recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

1. Does loading functions takes any parameters, known only on a project level, i.e. filepaths?
2. Is there any type of main library on which other libraries depends?

For example you have engine and extension libraries and application projects which depends on them.
You can make per-library functions loadCaches() so your projects's loading routine shkrinked to:

```
engine::loadCaches();
extension::loadCaches();
application::loadCaches();
```

If there main library exist, such as engine, and all kind of extensions depends on it, you can go further and introduce library handling interface in it:

```
namespace engine {
   LibraryDelegate {
      virtual void loadCaches() = 0;
   }

   void registerLibrary( LibraryDelegate* );
}
```

Now your project loading routine will look like this:

```
engine::registerLibrary( extensions::sharedLibraryDelegate() );
engine::registerLibrary( application::sharedLibraryDelegate() );
```

Pretty much the same, but with the gain of implementation encapsulated on the libraries level - your applications are now responsible only for libraries introduction to engine, with the rest of interaction going directly through library interface, which can be easily extended with unloadCaches() or whatever you want.